# Json Schema how to define a common restriction rule for all string fields in the schema

Tags: jsonschema

The string restriction I want to apply is: field should not contain `#` and `!` characters.

As the number of fields in my schema file is very huge I would like to define this restriction in one place and have it apply to all string fields.

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a schema which recursively applies to all array and object children, and has a `propertyNames` schema which specifies a pattern. Something like:

```json
{
  "$ref": "#/$defs/universalPropertyNames",
  "$defs": {
    "universalPropertyNames": {
      "propertyNames": {
        "pattern": "^[^!#]*$"
      },
      "items": {"$ref": "#/$defs/universalPropertyNames"},
      "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#/$defs/universalPropertyNames"}
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using JSON schema draft 7 or earlier, however, having a `$ref` means other validation keywords can't be used alongside it, and also $defs should be definitions. The following, wrapping that ref in an `allOf` can be integrated with your schema in earlier drafts.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/universalPropertyNames"}
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "universalPropertyNames": {
      "propertyNames": {
        "pattern": "^[^!#]*$"
      },
      "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/universalPropertyNames"},
      "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/universalPropertyNames"}
    }
  }
}
```